# Expressing modular functions of level 9 and 32 as rational functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, j-invariant

Let
$$\gamma_2(\tau)=j(\tau)^{1/3},\qquad \mathfrak f_1(\tau)=\frac{\eta(\tau/2)}{\eta(\tau)},$$

where $j$ is the modular invariant and $\eta$ is the Dedekind eta function. Cox in his *Primes of the form $x^2+ny^2$* shows that:

- $\gamma_2(3\tau)$ is a modular function for $\Gamma_0(9)$.
- $\mathfrak f_1(8\tau)$ is a modular function for $\Gamma_0{(32)}$.
- Every modular function for $\Gamma_0(N)$ is a rational function of $j(\tau)$ and $j(N\tau)$.

How to find explicitly the rational expressions for $\gamma_2(3\tau)$ and $\mathfrak f_1(8\tau)$ in $j(\tau)$ and $j(N\tau)$?

Comment: Such formulas tend to be unwieldy and of little use.
It's better to give $j := j(\tau)$ and $j' := j(N\tau)$ as 
modular functions for $\Gamma_0(N)$; if you absolutely need to write
some other modular function in terms of $j$ and $j'$ then you can do it
using elimination.  For example, the field of rational functions on 
$\Gamma_0(3)$ is rational, generated by $h := (\eta(\tau)/\eta(\tau^3))^{12}$;
then $j = (h+27)(h+243)^3/h^3$ and $j' = (h+3)^3 (h+27) / h$.
This also means that the first claim isn't right as stated because
$\gamma_2(3\tau) = \root 3 \of {j'} \notin {\bf C}(h)$.

Comment: @Noam D.Elkies, there should be 9 instead of 3.